# run casperjs from node app folder

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

Ok, let's make it simple :

I migrated my working node.js app to a new server today. The app spawns casperjs processes to do stuff.

**Problem :**

It doesn't run anymore

**Why?**

output casperjs --version from any folder but the one where my node app is installed :

```
root@xxxxx:/var# casperjs --version
1.1.0-beta3
```

now from the folder where my node app is installed :

```
root@xxxxx:/var/nodeapp# casperjs --version
Error: Cannot find module 'sys'

  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
  /var/nodeapp/node_modules/system/engines/node/system.js:8
  /var/nodeapp/node_modules/system/engines/node/system.js:45
1.1.0-beta3
```

Isn't that weird? :D Thanks for any insights

Edit : Tried uninstalling casper, then reinstalling from npm (I used github before). Same error.

Comment: Can you show the list of files/folders in your node app folder? I imagine one of them is being regarded as a config file by casper (or more likely phantom), when it is supposed to only apply to node.js. Or something like that.

Comment: good idea, I didn't think of that. Strange though that it works perfectly with casper 1.1.0-DEV

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uw28EH53 Here is the list

Comment: That was my reasoning too, 1.1.0-DEV was on my other server. I can't find it on github that's why! They have 1.1Beta1, 1.1 beta2... no DEV. Am I just being blind?

Answer (score 0):

-DEV was the previous version (see https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/commit/9f510ed68010b3fadc8842115a12d2712213779d#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2 ), up to about 4 months ago. So 1.1-beta2 should give you that.

You could also try getting the latest git version; you can see a list of changes since 1.1.0-beta3 here (I don't spot your problem though): https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/compare/1.1-beta3...master

By the way, are you running the same PhantomJS version on each of the working and non-working server? (Actually, what I would do next is upgrade your other server to first CasperJS 1.1-beta3, then the latest PhantomJS, and see if it breaks. If not, then it is not the software version but something else about the environment of the new server.)

Comment: I went back to phantomjs 1.9.0 to have the same version than on my old server, but the error persists. Also upgraded old server to casperjs beta3, and it didn't break... Now I'm really lost

Comment: Weird... I deleted the 'system' package in node_modules, and it's all good... But where did this thing come from? Could it have come from casper npm install? Anyways, working now, thanks for the support!